# Get all visible columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm struggling with angular ui grid.

Digging into their API I'm trying to find a way is it possible to get visible columns ( only visible ).

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs
```

returns all columns that are defined with all options. One solution will be that I iterate trough that array and filter out columns which have property `"visible" : true`, but I want to avoid that if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: loop through it..

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal yea... I did that at the end and it works. But I can't believe how there is no option to get that info, because there are hundred others.

Comment: @HarisHajdarevic Did my answer below help?  Under what circumstances are you trying to get the visible columns?  Can you share some more code?

Answer (score 2):

To get all visible columns:

```
options.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()
```

[ag grid columnApi Reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (depending on what you are ultimately trying to achieve):

```
uiGridExporterService.getColumnHeaders($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
```

If you can share a little more I might be able to help further.

Let me know if you have any other questions.